# Creating an MSI Package Using a Visual Studio Setup Project with PostBuildEvent

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am creating an MSI package using Visual Studio and I have added in the SQL Express set up, it all works fine, except I would like to automatically open the SQL Express when the application has finished installed.

I did a bit of investigating and saw an option in Visual Studio in the properties window for the Setup named `PostBuildEvent`. Can I add a custom macro here to boot the SQL Express installer? If so, how would I go about doing this? And if not, does anyone have any suggestions on how I could make this work?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post build event runs on your machine immediately after the build of the MSI file completes.  It will run code immediately after Visual Studio is completes building the MSI.  It will not run when an end-user installs the application.

To have the installer run code after the end-user installs the application use a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried this, during installation, the SQL Express installer starts and stops with the error `SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: The setting 'COMMIT' specified is not recognized. Error code 0x84B40003.`

Comment: I have removed the `/commit` in the Arguments field in the Properties for my SQL Installer. Works great now, thanks!